# Failed to register the bundle ID, while it is the bundle we use in the Firebase project

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui

I'm a new developer, and I'm working with my team to create an iOS app using SwiftUI and Firebase. So the problem is that one of my team members created a Firebase project and added my email to Users and Permissions.

When I cloned the project from GitHub and added the Bundle ID that is in the firebase, I had so many errors. This is an image of the errors in Xcode.

[image]

I want to work as a team using the same Firebase project, but I really do not know what the issue is. We created a team in App Store Connect to try to solve this problem and to share the Bundle ID that one of the team members created and added to her Apple developer account, but now we can't work as a team.

All of our Apple developer accounts are individual accounts.

Did anyone face the same problem, and how can we fix it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you need a business account

Comment: Using Firebase in your project is as simple as adding the packages and the Firebase JSON file which contains the keys and information about your Firebase. But about team settings, make sure that you are logged in to the Xcode with your account and that your account has been invited. Then in the "Team" dropdown menu you should be able to select the team and the errors should be gone